# How to configure specific dispatcher for Akka HTTP?

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, threadpool, akka-http

I have simple Akka HTTP application, which is used websocket. My request handler has blocking calls (like, JDBC). So, I need to use some fixed size thread pool to work with such code.

So, as I understand, I should use **application.conf** (like this - https://github.com/mkuthan/example-akka-http/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.conf). But I have no idea, how to configure custom thread pool with fixed constantly threads.

When I run my application and do thread dump, I see two name of threads:

- akka-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-62
- Routes-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-79

I don't understand, what are it these thread pools.

I tried to set up default thread pool, like this:

```
akka {
  actor {
    default-dispatcher {
      type = Dispatcher
      executor = "thread-pool-executor"
      thread-pool-executor {
        fixed-pool-size = 40
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it works super strange:

- Each thread pool have own 40 threads, so I have 80 threads. As I understand, each started dispatcher will have own 40 threads. It is bad.
- It is not FixedThreadPool - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int). When application starts. there is no any threads. Then, when application has processed some requests, threads are spawned. When there is no incoming requests for a while, threads have died.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably started two separate ActorSystems with two names `akka-system-akka` and `Routes-akka`, bacause of this you see two types of thread names in the logs.

`thread-pool-executor` is [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) defined by java runtime and it's not  FixedThreadPool.

> A ThreadPoolExecutor will automatically adjust the pool size (see
>   getPoolSize()) according to the bounds set by corePoolSize (see
>   getCorePoolSize()) and maximumPoolSize (see getMaximumPoolSize()).
>   When a new task is submitted in method execute(Runnable), and fewer
>   than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is created to
>   handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle. If there
>   are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize threads
>   running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is full. By
>   setting corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize the same, you create a
>   fixed-size thread pool. By setting maximumPoolSize to an essentially
>   unbounded value such as Integer.MAX_VALUE, you allow the pool to
>   accommodate an arbitrary number of concurrent tasks. Most typically,
>   core and maximum pool sizes are set only upon construction, but they
>   may also be changed dynamically using setCorePoolSize(int) and
>   setMaximumPoolSize(int).

So, you can see it starts with fewer than defined size and increases it thread count depending on incoming tasks.

Read section  for `Keep-alive times` that explains how threads are terminated.

Coming to the problem in hand:

Do not override `default-dispatcher` as it's being used by akka for other purposes, ie pass messages for execution to all actors, and this can be easily misconfigured. And, most importantly, do not run blocking tasks on default dispatcher (read [akka docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/dispatchers.html#blocking-needs-careful-management) for more details). Instead introduce a separate dispatcher and execute your blocking code there.

Here is an example how to do it with normal http request (sorry, I haven't used web sockets before)

```
  val asyncHandler: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = { req =>
    val blockingExecutionContext = system.dispatchers.lookup("blocking-dispatcher")
    Future {
      // blocking call 
      HttpRespone(???)
    }(blockingExecutionContext) // this can be passed implicitly too
  }
  Http().bindAndHandleAsync(asyncHandler, "localhost")
```

`blocking-dispatcher` must be configured in `application.conf` similar to what you did with `default-dispatcher` but it is defined in the root of the config file.

```
blocking-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    core-pool-size-min = 2
    core-pool-size-factor = 2.0
    core-pool-size-max = 10
  }
}
```

In general, isolate your blocking execution into separate execution context that you could configure specifically for this type of blocking operation. It is easier to fine-tune such approach as the types of execution tasks are limited and controlled by you.

Comment: Why are you not using a fixed-thread-pool size for the blocking-dispatcher ?

Comment: @DiegoRamos it can be used as well

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc would you recommend using a fixed size or a config like yours ? also is it necessary to add a Router? thanks for the reply.